# I've just been getting a DNS error when I want to integrate Mongodb in NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I've been getting an error for a few minutes when I want to use MongoDBAdapter within NextAuth. I'm using Next.js version 13.4.3 and route handlers

app/api/auth/[...nextAuth]/route.tsx:

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {

adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),

...
}
```

app/lib/mongoDBCLient.ts:

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
 throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

 const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
 const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NODE_ENV === "development") {

let globalWithMongo = global as typeof globalThis & {
 _mongoClientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>
}
if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
 client = new MongoClient(uri)
 globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
}
 clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise
} else {
 client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
 clientPromise = client.connect();
}


export default clientPromise;
```

> error ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/auth/gssapi.js:4:0
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns'